# PHP execution through Linux CLI

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

I'm quite new here on stackoverflow and I hope I will get some help because I already tried to find a solution with no success and I think I'm going to be crazy :)

Here is my problem :

I code a script with php which calls another API function.

When I call the php code through my browser, everything is ok.

When I call the php code through my terminal (php code.php), the script stops when it goes on the first function of the API and never comes back to my proper code.

Is it a tip to execute this code through CLI correctly?

Regards

Malkevia

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Youi need to give the code which you think is executed differently.

Comment: I have no error when I execute the code with CLI. The only thing is that the code enters on a function that belongs to an API (it's the mantis bt API) and at the end of this function, the code stops.

Answer (score 0):

You may try This
php -f somefile.php